# how can i dynamically change component in item renderer?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, mxml, flex-mobile

how can i dynamically change components text size in item renderer?

here is my CustomItemRenderer.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;

                invalidateDisplayList();
            }

            private function list_itemRendererFunc(item:Object):void {
                textArea2.setStyle("fontSize",
                                textArea2.getStyle("fontSize") + 2);    
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Label left="10" right="10" top="10" height="25" fontSize="14" maxDisplayedLines="1"
             text="{data.title}" textAlign="center"/>

    <s:TextArea id="textArea2" left="10" right="10" top="35" bottom="10" editable="false"
                fontSize="12" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin"
                text="{data.description }"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

when a button is pressed i want to access textArea2 and change font size.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Put bindable public var inside itemrenderer, then bind it to fontSize like:

```
<s:TextArea id="textArea2" fontSize="{mypublicvar}" ...
```

Then when button is pressed, loop over itemrenderers of list (or datagrid?), and change that renderer's mypublicvar to a new value, like:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < list.dataGroup.numElements; i++)
{
   var itemRendererItem:CustomItemRenderer = list.dataGroup.getElementAt(i) as CustomItemRenderer;
   itemRendererItem.mypublicvar += 2;

   //you can also try
   itemRendererItem.textArea2.setStyle("fontSize",...
}
```

BTW I think your list_itemRendererFunc is in wrong place, and you should make better formulated question.